# How to properly call a thunk function from a thunk promise?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a Delete function that uses Thunk to first dispatch a DELETE action through CALL_API middleware, and when the promise is resolved, it dispatches a GET action.

This code below performs the expected behaviour successfully.

```
  export const deleteShops = (shopId) => (dispatch, getState) => {

  let endpoint = `stores/${shopId}`;
  console.log('endpoint a enviar: ',endpoint)

  return dispatch({
    [CALL_API]: {
      // las acciones que ejecuta el middleware en loading, success y error.
      method: 'PATCH',
      types: [ SHOPS_DELETE_LOADING, SHOPS_DELETE_SUCCESS, SHOPS_DELETE_ERROR ],
      endpoint: endpoint,
      body: {
          "status" : "INACTIVE"
      },
      schema: Schemas.USER  // TODO: create a Schema for this
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log('termino el delete con respuesta: ', res);
    console.log('el state es: ', getState());
    let page = getState().shops.data.page.number;
    let pageSize = getState().shops.data.page.size;
    let endpoint = `stores/search/advancedSearch?page=${page}&size=${pageSize}&projection=storeProjection`;

    //getShops({page:page, pageSize:pageSize, filtered:[], sorted:[]})();
    return dispatch({
      [CALL_API]: {
        // las acciones que ejecuta el middleware en loading, success y error.
        method: 'GET',
        types: [ SHOPS_GET_LOADING, SHOPS_GET_SUCCESS, SHOPS_GET_ERROR ],
        endpoint: endpoint,
        schema: Schemas.USER
      }
    })

  })
}
```

What I would like to do is to pass another Thunk function instead of a dispatch, to avoid code duplication. Here's the action I want to pass to the promise.

```
  export const getShops = (state, instance) => (dispatch, getState) => {

  let endpoint = `stores/search/advancedSearch?page=${state.page}&size=${state.pageSize}&projection=storeProjection`;

  // more endpoint forming code here, not relevant

  // endpoint
  console.log('endpoint a enviar: ',endpoint)

  return dispatch({
    [CALL_API]: {
      // las acciones que ejecuta el middleware en loading, success y error.
      method: 'GET',
      types: [ SHOPS_GET_LOADING, SHOPS_GET_SUCCESS, SHOPS_GET_ERROR ],
      endpoint: endpoint,
      schema: Schemas.USER // TODO: create a Schema for this
    }
  })
}
```

And here is the modified deleteShops action.

```
export const deleteShops = (shopId) => (dispatch, getState) => {

  let endpoint = `stores/${shopId}`;
  console.log('endpoint a enviar: ',endpoint)

  return dispatch({
    [CALL_API]: {
      // las acciones que ejecuta el middleware en loading, success y error.
      method: 'PATCH',
      types: [ SHOPS_DELETE_LOADING, SHOPS_DELETE_SUCCESS, SHOPS_DELETE_ERROR ],
      endpoint: endpoint,
      body: {
          "status" : "INACTIVE"
      },
      schema: Schemas.USER // TODO: create a Schema for this
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log('termino el delete con respuesta: ', res);
    console.log('el state es: ', getState());
    let page = getState().shops.data.page.number;
    let pageSize = getState().shops.data.page.size;
    let endpoint = `stores/search/advancedSearch?page=${page}&size=${pageSize}&projection=storeProjection`;

    getShops({page:page, pageSize:pageSize})();

  })
}
```

When I make a delete, I get in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function
    at shops.js:47
    at shops.js:83
    at <anonymous>
```

My understanding is that Thunk is not passing the dispatch method to getShops. What would be the correct way to chain these actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the deleteShops function dispatching a function instead of an action. Notice on the last part that instead of executing the getShops function, I pass it to dispatch. Thunk middleware takes it from there.

```
export const deleteShops = (shopId) => (dispatch, getState) => {

  let endpoint = `stores/${shopId}`;
  console.log('endpoint a enviar: ',endpoint)

  return dispatch({
    [CALL_API]: {
      // las acciones que ejecuta el middleware en loading, success y error.
      method: 'PATCH',
      types: [ SHOPS_DELETE_LOADING, SHOPS_DELETE_SUCCESS, SHOPS_DELETE_ERROR ],
      endpoint: endpoint,
      body: {
          "status" : "INACTIVE"
      },
      schema: Schemas.USER // TODO: create a Schema for this
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log('termino el delete con respuesta: ', res);
    console.log('el state es: ', getState());
    let page = getState().shops.data.page.number;
    let pageSize = getState().shops.data.page.size;

    dispatch(getShops({page:page, pageSize:pageSize, sorted:[], filtered:[]}));

  })
}
```